# Build arrays out of struct

Tags: go

I'm trying to build two arrays from a struct. One with a list of properties the other with a list of values.

I made a few attempts base on some samples I found that use reflect (https://gist.github.com/justincase/5469009)

This is the closest I've come to a working implementation:

```
func main() {
    type Something struct {
        Some string
        Thing int
    }
    var props []string
    var vals []string

    m := Something{"smth", 666}
    s := reflect.ValueOf(&m).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        f := s.Field(i)
        props = append(props, s.Type().Field(i).Name)
        value, _ := fmt.Printf("%v", f.Interface())
        vals = append(vals, string(value))
    }
    fmt.Println(props)
    fmt.Println(vals)
}
```

I'm getting weird results after appending to the arrays

```
smth666[Some Thing]
[ ]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LZHtWx-Wbw1

Comment: Shh, shh, don't call it arrays.

Comment: They are arrays. What do you want me to call them? https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6

Comment: The types in your code are slices, the types in the link are arrays. The difference is explained in on the very next page

Comment: Those are not arrays, The link you've provided _does_ point to arrays, but that does not match your code, which uses slices, which are on the next page of the Tour: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it:

```golang
func main() {
    type Something struct {
        Some  string
        Thing int
    }
    var props []string
    var vals []string

    m := Something{"smth", 123}
    s := reflect.ValueOf(m)
    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        props = append(props, s.Type().Field(i).Name)
        vals = append(vals, fmt.Sprintf("%v", s.Field(i).Interface()))
    }

    fmt.Println(props)
    fmt.Println(vals)
}
```

Result:

```
[Some Thing]
[smth 123]
```

It also works with named fields like:

```golang
Something{
    Some:  "smth",
    Thing: 123,
}
```

Also as you need to an array (actually slice!) of strings (even if your values are in another type like int), You can use `fmt.Sprintf()` to convert `interface{}` to string

Answer (score -1):

your solution is overly complex there is no need for reflection, you should also converts int to string with strings.Itoa() not with simply callig string()

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    type Something struct {
        Some string
        Thing int
    }
    var props []string
    var vals []string

    var x = Something{
        Some:  "a name",
        Thing: 123,
    }
    props = append(props, x.Some)
    vals = append(vals, strconv.Itoa(x.Thing))

    fmt.Println(props)
    fmt.Println(vals)
}
```

[working example on go playground](https://play.golang.org/)

Comment: This doesn't do what I need: [Some Thing] [a name 123] One array with props onarray with values

Comment: @gyc this does excatly that, create one array with properties and one array with values

Comment: `props = append(props, x.Some)` this appends "a name" to the props array. Ran in the playground, it doesn't return [Some Thing] [a name 123]

Comment: @gyx excatly what is the use case for this? why would you need the names of the struct fields?